# Hibernate - How to use an Enumeration as Map's Key

Tags: xml, hibernate, dictionary, key, enumeration

My entity defines a field like

```
Map<String, String> props;
```

I've got this hibernate xml configuration

```
<map name="props" table="PROPS">  
    <key column="id"/>  
    <index column="name" type="string"/>  
    <element column="value" type="string"/>  
</map>
```

Now I want my Map to be an EnumMap like

```
Map<MyEnum, String> props;
```

I think I need to create my own Hibernate UserType for MyEnum and then reference this from the hbm.xml ...
Do you have any idea of what's the best/easiest way to achieve this?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate already has an [Enum](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/api/org/hibernate/type/EnumType.html) type. It's part of Hibernate Annotations distribution rather than Hibernate Core, however you can very much use it with XML mappings by specifying the type explicitly:

```
<property name="myEnum" type="org.hibernate.type.EnumType"/>
```

I haven't tried to specify Enum as map key, to be honest - I don't see why it wouldn't work, but [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/collections.html#collections-indexed) says that map key can be of "basic" type and it's possible that EnumType will not qualify.

Note, however, that your Map will NOT be an **EnumMap** when it's loaded from the database. Hibernate returns collections as its own types that implemented corresponding interfaces (e.g. Map / Set / List ...). If it's critical for you to have your Map as EnumMap (which it shouldn't be - other than minor performance improvement there should be no difference) than you will have to write a custom type - for Map itself, rather than Enum. It's rather hard, because for collections it would have to be dereferenceable in queries - I would strongly advice against going this route.

Answer (score 0):

Try [@MapKeyEnumerated](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/MapKeyEnumerated.html) annotation.